# Questions about Zakk Wylde's technique

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

Is Zakk Wylde's picking technique considered unusual? He rounds his right hand completely to the point that it looks unwieldy. Now he makes it work, there is no denying the result, but I wonder if you should aim to avoid a picking technique like that.

Comment: Turning my computer so that his guitar is about horizontal puts his right hand not that far from 'normal'.

Comment: I'm seeing back-edge picking which isn't too odd. Otherwise, nothing too unusual.